# Does Azure blob storage support alias for referring to a location or a file?

Tags: azure, alias, azure-blob-storage

Does Azure blob storage support alias for referring to a location or a file?

I am having an Azure subscription and would like to know if blob storage supports alias while referrring to a location or a file

If file is available like this - /storage/container/folderA/fileA

I want to do something like this -/foo/pointertofileA

which will still allow me to retrieve the file if I access the above url

Comment: What do you mean by alias? Can you please describe that?

Comment: You mean something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-custom-domain-name ?

Comment: @DavidMakogon edited my question

Answer (score 2):

There are no such path aliases with Azure Storage. You need to specify the blob's full URI.

Remember that Blob Storage is not the same as file I/O.

You may want to look at Azure Files, which attaches as SMB mount. Then you can use normal File I/O for accessing content.